# Dubious behaviour in multithreaded client-server in C

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, threadpool

`void* thread_request_server_static(void* args);` , This is where the worker threads will handle the connection (i have got 4 threads created)

**request.c**:

```
struct conn_args
{
  int fd;
  int filename;
  int filesize;
  struct conn_args *next;
}

/* other functions */

int add(int fd, char *filename, int filesize) 
{
    if(buffer_size >= buffer_max_size)
       return 1;
    
    struct conn_args *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct conn_args));

    temp->fd = fd;
    temp->filename = filename;
    temp->filesize = filesize;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) 
    {
       head = temp;
       tail = temp;
    } 
    else 
    {
      tail->next = temp;
      tail = temp;
    }
    buffer_size++;
    return 0;
}

struct conn_args* get_args()
{
  struct conn_args *temp = NULL;
  if(head!=NULL)
  {
    temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    buffer_size--;
  }
  return temp;
}

void *thread_request_serve_static(void *arg) 
{
  while (1) 
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    struct conn_args *arg = get_args();

    if (!arg)
      pthread_cond_wait(&c, &lock);
    else 
    {
      request_serve_static(arg->fd, arg->filename, arg->filesize);
      printf("Request for %s is removed from the buffer\n-----------------\n",
             arg->filename);
      close_or_die(arg->fd);
      free(arg);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }

  // TODO: write code to actualy respond to HTTP requests
}

void request_handle(int fd) 
{

 /* variable declarations and condition checks */

 pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
 int stat = add(fd, filename, sbuf.st_size);
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

 if (!stat) 
 {
    printf("-----------------\nRequest for %s is added to the buffer\n",
      filename);
    pthread_cond_signal(&c);     // wake up thread since connections arrive at the buffer.
 } 
 else 
 {
    printf("Server overload: Try again later!");
 }
```

}

**wserver.c**:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   /* variable initializations and argument reading */

pthread_t thread_pool[num_threads];
for(int i=0; i<num_threads; i++)
    pthread_create(&thread_pool[i], NULL, thread_request_serve_static, NULL);

// open the socket connection
int listen_fd = open_listen_fd_or_die(port);
while (1) {
    
    // start accepting HTTP requests from client
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;

    int client_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    int conn_fd = accept_or_die(listen_fd, (sockaddr_t *) &client_addr, (socklen_t *) &client_len);
    

    // process the HTTP request
    request_handle(conn_fd);
    
    // close the connection to client
    //close_or_die(conn_fd);    // this has to be carefully done at the correct time in request.c
}
```

Starting the server,

```
./wserver -p 8003   (port 8003)
```

bash file for testing multiple connections,

**multiple_clients.bash**:

```
echo Starting requests

for ((i=15;i>0;i-=1))
do
    ./wclient localhost 8003 /files/test$i.html &
done

echo Requests completed
```

I piped the output into a test.txt and got the following, `bash multiple_clients.bash > test.txt`

**test.txt**:

```
 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file -------------- 15.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file ------------ 13.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file ------------ 13.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file ---------- 11.
 /* Meta data */
 
 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file --------- 10.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file ---------- 11.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file ----- 6.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file 1.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file - 2.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file --- 4.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file - 2.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file -------- 9.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file -- 3.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file ---- 5.
 /* Meta data */

 /* Meta data */
  This is a test HTML file ------- 8.
 /* Meta data */
```

As you can see, some files are getting repeated and some are not showing up (7 and 14). Why is this? Although the total output file count is 15, this probably means it is successfully adding all the files to the buffer, but somehow skipping some files and producing duplicates of others.

The program doesn't even crash on double free error, so how is a single file getting handled twice?

Do let me know if any more info is required.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `request_handle()` references variables named `filename` and `sbuf.st_size` that do not appear to be declared anywhere.  It's not clear how that code can compile, unless there are global variables declared somewhere; and if there are global variables declared, they may be introducing race conditions.

Comment: I have written ```/* variable declarations and condition checks */``` at the beginning of the function. Shall I post the full ```request_handle()```? The only global thing the threads are accessing are the ```struct conn_args```

Comment: Any Ideas? Right now when I am running it a couple of times, no duplicates are produced and all requests get handled... wtf is going on.

Comment: It’s probably a race condition.  I suggest simplifying the program until you have the smallest possible version that still reproduces the fault.  Then, if you haven’t figured out the problem as part of that process, post the code so that others can compile and run it and test it on their own machines.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Having stared at my screen for the past 2 day, I am honestly clueless at this point. Everything seems correct, locks, condition variables, frees. I know SO doesn't appreciate dump-your-code-to-fix type of questions, but I really want to resolve this. Heres the zip: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fUJR5y8dSyVsH5iRfp8N1MU6xyb8LsMi/view?usp=share_link Thanks

Comment: You can take the bash file from my question above. Or just comment out the outer for loop.

Comment: We're still waiting for that [mre].  If you're not sure what we mean by the term then follow the link to a description.

Comment: However, I note that you dispatch all your test requests very close together.  You don't show the backlog parameter of the listening socket, but it is conceivable that you are making too many connection attempts in too short a time.  That would manifest as some of the clients failing to connect.

Comment: I note also that your `thread_request_serve_static()` function appears to spend all its time holding the mutex locked, except when it is blocked waiting on the CV.  This means that although your server is technically multithreaded, all request service is actually serialized.  In fact, you can't even enqueue a new request while handling a different one.

Comment: Failing to connect means we also fail to enqueue the arguments. But if you look, everytime you run the bash files, theres exactly 15 file outputs. No less No more. If you change the for loop to run from 1 to 10, then theres exactly 10 file outputs. So it means, somehow it does see and enqueue all the connections, But skipping some files and producing the exact same number of duplicates of others.

Comment: "function appears to spend all its time holding the mutex locked". How do I implement then? all the threads do is dequeue (critical section) and writes it to the std output (again critical if we care about getting the output in one piece). I would do like to say I don't plan to deploy it anywhere. Just an exercise to get a feel of threads in C.